# JavaScript "example" of a switch to compare HTML button id's

Tags: javascript, button, switch-statement, this

I posted a question a week ago about how to use JavaScript switch statement to compare this.id. I found it hard to get my function/object methods out of the switch as variables. Using strict mode and trying to do this seems impossible. However I did find one way to get the results I wanted.

```js
    "use strict"

    function fragmentLoader() {
      getID(this.id);
    }

    function getID(x) {
      var theID = x;

      switch (theID) {
        case "myFirstID":
          myDate();

          break;

        case "mySecondID":
          changeStyle();

          break;

        case "myThirdID":
          myText();

          break;

        default:
          otpt = "ERROR!";
      }

    }

    function myDate() {
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = Date();
    }

    function changeStyle() {
      
         var whatColor = document.getElementById("content").style.color;
      
      if ( whatColor === "black") {
        document.getElementById("content").style.color = "blue";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("content").style.color = "black";
      }

    }

    function myText() {
      document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = "This Text will display";
    }
    document.getElementById("content").style.color = "black";
    document.querySelector('#myFirstID').addEventListener('click', fragmentLoader);
    document.querySelector('#mySecondID').addEventListener('click', fragmentLoader);
    document.querySelector('#myThirdID').addEventListener('click', fragmentLoader);
```

```html
    <div>
      <div>
        <button id="myFirstID">
          Press for Date and Time.
        </button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button id="mySecondID">
          Press to change style color.
        </button>
      </div>

      <div>
        <button id="myThirdID">
          Press for Text.
        </button>
      </div>

      <p id="content">content here

      </p>
    </div>
```

Had to laugh at my example because for some odd reason it takes 2 clicks to get the style to change. Any ideas as to why? NOTE : " This is now FIXED"

Other than that I hope this helps someone else.
 -Rob

Comment: The initial call to document.getElementById("content").style.color; is not returning "black".  It then sets the color to black and on the second press it is "black" and sets the color to "blue".

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is the reason your code does not work as expected:

```
document.getElementById("content").style.color === "black";
```

You're trying to initially set the color to black, but you used to many "=" signs. Change that line to:

```
document.getElementById("content").style.color = "black";
```

... and your code will work!